# How can i re-write this haskell function complexity

Tags: haskell

```
c:: Integer -> Integer
c n | n < 3 = n + 100
    | otherwise = c (n-2) + c (n-3) + c (n-2)
```

Complexity of c in this form is exponential. Rewrite function c so that it's complexity is linear.
c x should terminate if 1000 < x 100000.

Comment: This is not a “do my homework for me” site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is quite clearly a homework question.

Comment: I agree that this should be closed, but let us be clear here: it is not because this is a homework question, it is because the author clearly put no effort of their own into finding an answer. [Well-researched homework questions where we have a chance of teaching something are great additions to the site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 6):

Use [Data.Memocombinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.5.1/docs/Data-MemoCombinators.html):

```
import Data.MemoCombinators

c:: Integer -> Integer
c n | n < 3 = n + 100
    | otherwise = c' (n-2) + c' (n-3) + c' (n-2)

c' = integral c

main = print $ c' 1000
```

Note how `c` was re-written to call `c'` which is the memoized version of `c`.

Comment: Gotta be the most useful, informative non-answer I've seen. (That is meant positively.)